# How to use index in @for in html angular 17

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular17

How can I define the `index` variable in `@for` in Angular 17

```
const users = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Ali' },
    { id: 2, name: 'reza' },
    { id: 3, name: 'jack' },
  ];

<ul>
  @for (user of users; track user.id; let i = index) {
  <li>{{ user.name + i }}</li>
  } @empty {
  <span>Empty list of users</span>
  }
</ul>
```

index is not known as we had in `*ngFor` and got `Unknown "let" parameter variable "index" in Angular17 @for`

But the following is working:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index">{{ user.name + i }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `$index` everywhere in the scope of the `@for` block without having to alias it:

```
<ul>
  @for (user of users; track user.id) {
     <li>{{ user.name + $index }}</li>
  } @empty {
     <span>Empty list of users</span>
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: Then I think we can have it like this: `let i = $index`?

Answer (score 1):

you can also write this

```html
<ul>
  @for (user of users; track user.id; let idx = $index) {
     <li>{{ user.name + idx }}</li>
  } @empty {
     <span>Empty list of users</span>
  }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for your answer also I have found some other contextual variables rather than `$index` [Here](https://angular.io/api/core/for):

| Variable | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| $count | Number of items in a collection iterated over |
| $index | Index of the current row |
| $first | Whether the current row is the first row |
| $last | Whether the current row is the last row |
| $even | Whether the current row index is even |
| $odd | Whether the current row index is odd |

and the usage would be:

```
@for (item of items; track item.id; let idx = $index, e = $even) {
  Item #{{ idx }}: {{ item.name }}
}
```

We can also utilize our existing template and execute this command to migrate to `control-flow`.

```
ng g @angular/core:control-flow
```